# How Many Marriages in a Bipartite Graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given two disjoint sets, say $M$ and $W$, both of size $n$, I want to compute how many possibilities of marriage exist.

For example, when $n=1$, there are two marriages only: either $m_1-w_1$ or $\emptyset$, denoting no marriage.

When $n=2$, there are 7: ($m_1-w_1,m_2-w_2$), ($m_1-w_2,m_2-w_1$), $m_1-w_1$, $m_1-w_2$, $m_2-w_1$, $m_2-w_2$, and $\emptyset$.

When $n=3$, there are 61 (6 with 3 couples, 36 with 2 couples only, 18 with 1 couple only, and 1 with no couple).

Which is the answer for an arbitrary $n$? I have been thinking about it. If I get an answer soon I will post it but yet I see no pattern. Please answer only if you have given the question some thought, it is by no means a trivial question, at least in my humble opinion.

Thanks for intuitive answers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To form exactly $k$ couples, select $\binom nk$ partners on either side and marry them in $k!$ different ways. Thus the total is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2k!\;.
$$

This is [OEIS sequence A002720](https://oeis.org/A002720) (lots of information in that entry). According to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20binom%20%28n,k%29%5E2%20*%20k!%20for%20k%3D0..n&dataset=), it's also $U(-n,1,-1)$, where $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind.

Some of your counts are wrong. For $n=3$, there are only $18$ options with $2$ couples and $9$ with $1$ couple; the total is $34$.

Comment: I have been wondering what is the number for mutipartner marriages. I thought I could only change $k^2$ for a different thing, but I guess that is not true as now I can't choose the partner that way. Any idea about that?

Comment: @JosuéOrtega: If by multipartner marriages you mean marriages between any non-empty subset of $M$ and any non-empty subset of $W$, to form $k-1$ such marriages, you can partition both $M$ and $W$ into $k$ parts, match them up in $k!$ ways and choose one of the $k$ pairs to remain unmarried, so the total is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{{n\atop k}\right\}^2k!k\;,
$$

where $\left\{{n\atop k}\right\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: @JosuéOrtega: Actually, that only counts the cases where at least one person on each side remains unmarried; we need to add the cases where no-one remains unmarried,

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{{n\atop k}\right\}^2k!\;,
$$

and the cases where only on one side people remain unmarried,

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{{n\atop k}\right\}\left\{{n\atop{k-1}}\right\}k!\;.
$$

Comment: I actually think that makes sense. I will do it myself to prove it but seems reasonable. I think I will use this result in an academic paper of mine, so I would like to acknowledge you in there. You can send me your details to josue.ortega1@gmail.com or I could send you the paper if you want to.

Comment: I actually went through your calculations and we mean different things. Imagine one side is ${a,b}$ and the other side is ${1,2}$. Now I want to count all possible marriages, which are i: $[\mu(a)=\{1,2\}, \mu(b)=\{1,2\}]$, ii $[\mu(a)=\{1,2\}, \mu(b)=\{1\}]$, iii $[\mu(a)=\{1,2\}, \mu(b)=\{2\}]$, iv $[\mu(a)=\{1,2\}, v\mu(b)=\emptyset]$, v $[\mu(a)=\{1\}, \mu(b)=\{1,2\}]$, vi $[\mu(a)={2}, \mu(b)=\{1,2\}]$, vii $[\mu(a)=\emptyset, \mu(b)=\{1,2\}]$, viii $[\mu(a)=\{1\}, \mu(b)=\{2\}]$, ix $[\mu(a)=\{2\}, \mu(b)=\{1\}]$...I mean you see the pattern.

Comment: @JosuéOrtega: I'm afraid I don't. You paired $\mu(a)=\{1,2\}$ with every subset for $b$; then you paired $\mu(b)=\{1,2\}$ with every subset for $a$; and then you added two more pairings for which I don't see a pattern. Unless this is a horribly complicated way of saying that each of $\mu(a)$ and $\mu(b)$ can indepedently be any subset of $\{1,2\}$, I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Suppose now there are two men, $a$ and $b$, and two women, say $x$ and $y$. A matching $\mu$ allows anybody to have two wives or husbands, or one, or none. Matching ii above specifies that guy $a$ marries both women $x,y$, but $b$ only marries woman $a$. This is like polygamy. Marriage vii says that $a$ marries no one, but the two women marry guy $b$. I counted and found 16 of such marriages. But the generalization does not come close to this. I hope I made myself clear :S

Comment: @JosuéOrtega: I still don't understand. I'd suggested that you might simply be choosing subsets independently, and from the fact that you didn't respond to that suggestion I gather that this isn't what you're doing; but then I don't see the difference. You say you "counted" $16$ possibilities, but in your description I don't find anything that requires counting. Clearly there are $4\cdot4=16$ ways to independently choose one of $4$ subsets for each of $\mu(a)$ and $\mu(b)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42018/discussion-between-josue-ortega-and-joriki).